# Преобразовать string в time формата "дд:чч:мм:сс" в DateTime

Tags: c#

У меня поле `1:1:4:0` типа string формата `дд:чч:мм:сс`. Как преобразовать это значение так, чтобы было DateTime. То есть время будущего понедельника, 1 час 4 минуты 0 секунд?

Можно использовать метод `timespan`? Если да, то как ?

```
string dbStr = row["shedule_dt_send_daytime"].ToString();
string tmnmru = row["timer_name_ru"].ToString().ToUpper();

DateTime dtbeg = Convert.ToDateTime(row["shedule_dt_beg"]);
DateTime dtend = Convert.ToDateTime(row["shedule_dt_period_end"]);


//Разделяем строку на части
string[] splitStr = dbStr.Split(':');
Console.WriteLine(splitStr);

// Получаем требуемый день недели.    
int targetDayOfWeek = int.Parse(splitStr[0]);
int targetHourOfDay = int.Parse(splitStr[1]);
int targetMinuteOfHour = int.Parse(splitStr[2]);
int target5MinuteOfHour = int.Parse(splitStr[2]);
int target10MinuteOfHour = int.Parse(splitStr[2]);
int target30MinuteOfHour = int.Parse(splitStr[2]);

// Получим текущий день,час,минут  недели
int nowDayOfWeek = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
int nowHour = (int)DateTime.Now.Hour;
int nowMinute = (int)DateTime.Now.Minute;
int now5Minute = (int)DateTime.Now.Minute;
int now10Minute = (int)DateTime.Now.Minute;
int now30Minute = (int)DateTime.Now.Minute;
DateTime startDay = DateTime.Now;


switch (tmnmru)
{
    case "ЧАС":

        if ((targetMinuteOfHour != nowMinute) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(3))))
        {
            int waitMinute = (nowMinute < targetMinuteOfHour) ? targetMinuteOfHour - nowMinute : (60 - nowMinute) + targetMinuteOfHour;
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(waitMinute);

            Console.WriteLine(splitStr[2]); //мм 
        }

        break;

    case "НЕДЕЛЯ":

        if ((targetDayOfWeek != nowDayOfWeek) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(2))))
        {    // Посчитаем разницу между днями 
            int waitDay = (nowDayOfWeek < targetDayOfWeek) ? targetDayOfWeek - nowDayOfWeek : (7 - nowDayOfWeek) + targetDayOfWeek;
            // Вычислим время запуска
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(waitDay);

            Console.WriteLine(splitStr[0] + ":" + splitStr[1]);//дд:чч
        }

        break;

    case "ДЕНЬ":

        if ((targetHourOfDay != nowHour) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(2))))
        {
            int waithour = (nowHour < targetHourOfDay) ? targetHourOfDay - nowHour : (24 - nowHour) + targetHourOfDay;
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddHours(waithour);


            Console.WriteLine(splitStr[1] + ":" + splitStr[2]); //чч:мм
        }
        break;

    case "МИНУТ":

        if ((targetMinuteOfHour != nowMinute) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(3))))
        {
            int waitMinute = (nowMinute < targetMinuteOfHour) ? targetMinuteOfHour - nowMinute : (60 * 5 - nowMinute) + targetMinuteOfHour;
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(waitMinute);

            Console.WriteLine(splitStr[3]); //сс
        }

        break;
    case "5 МИНУТ":
        if ((target5MinuteOfHour != now5Minute) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(3))))
        {
            int wait5Minute = (now5Minute < target5MinuteOfHour) ? target5MinuteOfHour - now5Minute : (60 * 5 - now5Minute) + target5MinuteOfHour;
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(wait5Minute);

            Console.WriteLine(splitStr[3]); //cc
        }

        break;

    case "10 МИНУТ":
        if ((target10MinuteOfHour != now10Minute) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(3))))
        {
            int wait10Minute = (now10Minute < target10MinuteOfHour) ? target10MinuteOfHour - now10Minute : (60 * 10 - now10Minute) + target10MinuteOfHour;
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(wait10Minute);

            Console.WriteLine(splitStr[3]);
        }

        break;

    case "30 МИНУТ":

        if ((target30MinuteOfHour != now30Minute) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(3))))
        {
            int wait30Minute = (now30Minute < target30MinuteOfHour) ? target30MinuteOfHour - now30Minute : (60 * 30 - now30Minute) + target30MinuteOfHour;
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(wait30Minute);

            Console.WriteLine(splitStr[3]);
        }
        break;


    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Такого таймера нету");
        break;

}

// Вычислим время запуска
if ((startDay > dtbeg) && (startDay < dtend))
{
    DateTime startTime = new DateTime(startDay.Year, startDay.Month, startDay.Day, int.Parse(splitStr[1]), int.Parse(splitStr[2]), int.Parse(splitStr[3]));

    Console.WriteLine("Таймер должен запуститься в : {0} ", startTime.ToString());




    // Узнаем разницу в миллисекундах, оставшуюся до запуска

    double waitTime_ms = (startTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine("До запуска осталось: {0} мс.", waitTime_ms);





    MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer();


    myTimer.Interval = waitTime_ms;
    myTimer.s_id = Convert.ToString(row["shedule_id"]);
    myTimer.alg = Convert.ToString(row["meta_cod"]);
    myTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeout;
    myTimer.AutoReset = true;
    myTimer.datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(startTime);
    myTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

сейчас время 11:38, запуск 1:04. Как решить проблему? Попробовал  `DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(2)`
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что формат у вас примерно такой: "день недели:часы:минуты:секунды" ?

Comment: А зачем вы в БД mssql храните дате в строковом виде?

Comment: И что? Почему нельзя хранить дату как дату?

Comment: Так все-таки, почему?

Comment: Вы неправильно выделяете код в вопросе, нужно выделить код и нажать кнопку `{}`. Больше не добавляйте код как snippet, это для HTML/CSS/JS

Comment: @MaximK доброе утро! посмотрите пожалуйста(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для получения DatiTime понедельника 1 час 4 минуты, нужно проделать следующие операции:

```
 string dbStr = "1:1:4:0";
        Console.WriteLine(dbStr);            

        //Разделяем строку на части
        string[] splitStr = dbStr.Split(':');

        // Получаем требуемый день недели.
        int targetDayOfWeek = int.Parse(splitStr[0]);
        // получим русское имя дня недели
        string targetDayName = (new CultureInfo("ru-RU")).DateTimeFormat.DayNames[targetDayOfWeek%7];
        Console.WriteLine("Таймер должен запуститься в "+targetDayName.ToUpper());

        // Получим текущий день недели
        int nowDayOfWeek = (int) DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
        string nowDayName = (new CultureInfo("ru-RU")).DateTimeFormat.DayNames[nowDayOfWeek%7];

        // День старта
        DateTime startDay = DateTime.Now;

        // Если день старта не сегодня или сегодня, но уже время прошло            
        if ((targetDayOfWeek != nowDayOfWeek) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(2))))            
        {
            Console.Write("Время запуска уже прошло. ");
            // Посчитаем разницу между днями 
            int waitDay = (nowDayOfWeek < targetDayOfWeek) ? targetDayOfWeek - nowDayOfWeek : (7 - nowDayOfWeek) + targetDayOfWeek;
            Console.WriteLine("Нужно подождать еще: {0} дней", waitDay);
            // прибавим вычисленное количество дней
            startDay = DateTime.Now.AddDays(waitDay);
        }            

        // Вычислим время запуска            
        DateTime startTime = new DateTime(startDay.Year, startDay.Month, startDay.Day, int.Parse(splitStr[1]), int.Parse(splitStr[2]), int.Parse(splitStr[3]));

        Console.WriteLine("Таймер будет запущен : {0}", startTime.ToString());
        // Узнаем разницу в миллисекундах, оставшуюся до запуска
        double waitTime_ms = (startTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("До запуска осталось - {0} мс.", waitTime_ms);Результат будет следующим:
```

[image: Кажется это то, что вам надо]

Comment: %7 - подправил, ниже точно такая же строка

Comment: с `foreach` -ом

Comment: конечно... В конце ты получил значение в мс до начала работы таймера.

Comment: где тут указать,что делает таймер, и как поставить интервал: `myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(startTime);`  ??

Comment: не `startTime`, a `waitTime_ms`

Comment: добрый день! поставил в интервал `myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToDouble(waitTime_ms);` не работает что то

Comment: не запустился сегодня ночью7

Comment: поможете с таймером?

Comment: Поможем. я подправил ответ, для случая если время сегодня

Comment: с интервалом `waitTime_ms`  что то не так?

Comment: можете подробно объяснить про `DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(2))`

Comment: Если время сейчас больше времени запуска сегодня

Comment: не работает у меня что то. `dbStr.Substring(3)` а так? поможете?

Comment: @propro17 пожалуйста хватит уже редактировать вопрос, MaximK если Вы помогаете ТС с решением проблемы в режиме *техподдержки* то может Вы создадите чат, в котором обсудите все тонкости, и дадите *полностью готовое решение*, дабы уже закрыть окончательно этот вопрос

Comment: @propro17, MaximK [присоединяйтесь](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41139/string--time----datetime)

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что получится одним оператором. Попробуйте разделить входную строку отдельно на "день недели" и "время" и дальше уже парсить.
День недели можно получить вот таким способом:

```
int dayNumber = 1; // понедельник например
CultureInfo russian = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
string dayOfWeek = russian.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[dayNumber%7];
```

Ну а время парсить через DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "HH:mm:ss", russian);

Comment: я обновил вопрос)

Comment: `dayNumber%7` как работает. Поясни пожалуйста

Comment: @MaximK DayNames это перечисление с днями недели, причем воскресенье имеет индекс 0. Чтобы корректно отображать дни недели и не выйти за границы массива используем остаток от деления на 7.

Answer (score 0):

Для преобразования "**1:1:4:0**" к "**Понедельник, 1 час 4 минуты 0 сек**", нужно сделать следующее:

```
string dbStr = "1:1:4:0";
int dayOfWeek = int.Parse(dbStr[0]);
string dayName = (new CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).DateTimeFormat.DayNames[dayOfWeek%7];
// Получим "Понедельник"

DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(2));
string timeStr = string.Format("{0} час {1} минуты {2} секунды",time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Seconds);

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", dayName, timeStr);
```

Comment: int.Parse(dbStr[0].ToString());

Comment: Посчитай количество мс до необходимого времени старта используя только время

Comment: `if ((targetDayOfWeek != nowDayOfWeek) || (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dbStr.Substring(2))))`

Comment: && - это И, || - это ИЛИ

Comment: @propro17 у тебя таймер запускается в нужное время?

Comment: да, запускается. Теперь мне надо поставить условия.

Comment: попробовал через `switch` , можно так или нет?

Comment: я обновил вопрос!